# Ingesting professional sony beta and sx tape into iMac thru Canopus ADVC 110

Tags: video

I'm trying to capture sony beta and sx tape into my iMac. I know I need a device between the deck and computer. I believe that device is the Canopus ADVC 110 converter (have yet to purchase this.)  Will I be able to cable from that converter directly to the thunderbolt port on the iMac? There are no firewire ports on my iMac. Pretty confused on this process. thanks!

Comment: The Canopus ADVC 110 will output DV video which may or may not be desired.

Answer (score 1):

If you have firwire device but no firewire port you need an adapter. Apple offers one:
http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD464ZM/A/apple-thunderbolt-to-firewire-adapter

If you tape deck is offering an output that the Canopus supports you will be able to capture your tapes that way.
Alternatively you might want to look for a USB based solution that might be cheaper than using this device with an adapter.

Comment: ok thanks! So the adapter carries both audio and video from the Canopus converter? Will I need any to download any program if I'm capturing directly to an external hard drive plugged into the iMac?

Comment: Also could you recommend a usb solution? thanks!

Comment: No, if your hard drive is internal or external makes absolutely no difference when capturing with any sort of device.
I can't really recommend you anything as I dont know what you are playing back from but all you need really is a device that can capture analog video, like the Canopus.
A cheap capture stick can do the same but maybe not with the same quality. Though that can be delectable if you dont plan on further editing the footage and just want to save some home videos.
http://www.amazon.com/Elgato-Video-Capture-Device-10020840/dp/B0029U2YSA/

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking for an interface that offers SDI inputs (as I suppose both your SP and SX players have SDI outputs) with which you will have better results than with a composite inputs as is on the Canopus product.

SDI interface will allow syncing your interface with the player, and get embedded audio directly in the SDI stream.

An example of such interfaces is https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/ultrastudiousb3, other products might exist.